# codeigniter failed when use is_ajax_request function on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to update user password from panel admin with ajax request is use **is_ajax_request()** on the controller but this function says I'm not in ajax request. why does this happen?

Here's my ajax jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlTarget,
    traditional: true,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {currentPassword:currentPassword, newPassword:newPassword},
    success: function ( result ) {
        if( result.status == 'success' ){
            window.location = baseUrl;
        }else{
            $("#login-invalid-input").show();
            $("#login-submit").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    },
    error: ajax_error_handling
});
```

on the controller:

```
    private function ajax_checking(){
        if ( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
            redirect( base_url() );
        }
    }

    public function change_password(){
        $this->ajax_checking();
        $this->load->model("admin_model");

        $postData = $this->input->post();
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id_admin');

        if($this->admin_model->check_current_password($id, $postData['currentPassword'])){
            $this->admin_model->change_password($id, $postData['newPassword']);
            $send["status"] == "success";
        }else
            $send["status"] == "fail";

        echo json_encode($send);
    }
```

since the result of `ajax_checking` is false the system redirect me to the set url. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help smit,
here's the problem that redirect me to baseUrl :

i set this on the controller,
it happens because i have this script on the controllers that redirect me to the basicUrl:

```
    public function __Construct() {
        parent::__Construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') ) {
            redirect( base_url() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: so it was not about ajax checking, but it's about check session userdata

Answer (score 0):

`is_ajax_request()` , this function checks to see if the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH server header has been set, if set response will be true otherwise false means it will returns a boolean response.

In your constants.php file you can add this :

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

then in your code instead of

```
private function ajax_checking(){
    if ( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
        redirect( base_url() );
    }
}
```

use

```
private function ajax_checking(){
    if ( !IS_AJAX ) {
        redirect( base_url() );
    }
}
```

### Update

set header in every ajax request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'xmlhttprequest');
    }
});
```

Comment: it's still same, the result is same with is_ajax_request() ?

Comment: Please check update in my answer, let me know if it works? @ana

Comment: oh i find the answer after so many tries include from you, thanks smit,

Comment: Can you please post the answer so it can help someone in future? @ana

Comment: it happens because i have this script on the controllers that redirect me to the basicUrl:

        public function __Construct() {
            parent::__Construct();
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') ) {
                redirect( base_url() );
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar issue with CodeIgniter when `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` did not work on my CentOS Server with Centos Web Panel Installed (CWP), while it worked fine on my localhost.

My solution was to add the following in top of my JavaScript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    }
});
```

As the live server was not sending header `X-Requested-With` which CodeIgniter needs to recognize Ajax request.